# geoview is not showing any output

Tags: python, maps, datashader

i am trying to visualize a very large data points on the map for that i am using datashade, I am trying to work on chicago crime dataset: https://www.kaggle.com/currie32/crimes-in-chicago . I am following the guidselines given in this tutorial- (https://towardsdatascience.com/large-scale-visualizations-and-mapping-with-datashader-d465f5c47fb5) 
Here's a look at my dataset:
[image]
(easting and northing are the projected values of latitude and longitude)

The below code is supposed to give me the map visualisation of all my points, But i am not getting any output not even a single line of plain text

```
 # Map of all businesses colored by category.
from colorcet import bmw
url="http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer/tile/{Z}/{Y}/{X}.png"
geomap = gv.WMTS(url)
points = hv.Points(gv.Dataset(dask_df, kdims=['easting', 'northing'], vdims=['IUCR']))
biz_cat = dynspread(datashade(points, color_key=bmw, element_type=gv.Image, aggregator=ds.count()))
geomap*biz_cat
```

Comment: Are you trying to visualize biz_cat? So far you've created it but not actually done anything with it.  E.g. if you are in Jupyter you can put `biz_cat` as the last line in a cell, to view that object; these plots work the same as for integers, strings, etc., in that they are displayed only if they are the result of that cell.

Comment: Hi, James, I couldn't understand the solution you mentioned do you mean I have to remove "geomap "biz_cat" and keep only "biz_cat" in the last line and yes I am using jupyter notebooks

Comment: Oh, I think I misread your code as it was formatted by SO;  `geomap * biz_cat` should work fine if it's on a line by itself. Did you call `hv.extension('bokeh')` to load the JavaScript needed first?